# Python: Import Exception

Tags: python, import, set, intersection

Is it possible to import everything except one module from a package?

I need a lot of modules from a particular library that I use in my class, but it looks like it used the same module name for one of the modules that I need.

I need to use set operation and intersection, but when I import that library from my class, it gives me an error because of that.

I didn't want to import it separately or put the name in front of every methods since I'm using it a lot.

Is there a way for the python to import everything except for a particular method like `set`? 
Or maybe import the `set` part again later?

Comment: `from ~ import *` is not valid syntax. It would help if you'd mention *what* module you are using and the *exact* statement you are trying to use to import it, rather than leaving us to guess all that.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, you have a module that defines `set`? Can you show us example code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for them to declare a ```set``` function... is it?  Could you share the import statement?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Yes, it is possible to create a `set` function, and just about anything else (int, float, str, dict, etc) -- the only thing you cannot create your own versions of are keywords (None, else, etc).  Of course, you would want a *really* good reason to create your own version.

Comment: oh it's called "myro" which includes functions for the robot that we use the class. It looks like "set" is a function used for the robot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no terminology to `from ... import * except blah, bleh, bluh`.  You can either write your own import function to support it, or do something like:

```
from xyz import *
del set
```

which will stop shadowing the built-in `set` so you can use it again.  Then if you need the `xyz.set` function you can do:

```
from xyz import set as xyzset
```

Note:  `from ... import *` is not *usually* good practice, and you should make sure the modules you are using this way support it -- if they don't explicity say they were designed to be used this way, then you shouldn't (unless you enjoy debugging weird problems later ;).

Comment: ooh.. This worked! Thanks a lot!! Didn't think about using del :D I will keep in mind about the from ... import * part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want would be:

```
from thing import a, b, c, d, e, f
```

which will import `a, b, c, d, e, f` from `thing`.

AFAIK, there is no way to do an `from thing import all but a, b, c`
thats why

```
import thing
thing.a
```

exists in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what's going on (giving actual module names might help). But it's generally considered bad practice to do `from ... import *` at all, because then it's not obvious where particular things are coming from. Instead, do `from ... import thingA, thingB, thingC`.

You could also do `import ... as shortname`, and then refer to the methods as `shortname.whatever` (where `shortname` could obviously be something very short).